# How to build and deploy GeoExplorer on jboss 5.1.x?

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I am trying to deploy opengeo GeoExplorer on jboss 5.1.x by using this command:

```
ant deploy -Dcargo.host=localhost -Dcargo.port=8080 -Dcargo.container=jboss51x -Dcargo.username=abc -Dcargo.password=abc123
```

but GeoExplorer fails to build successfully.

Here is the log containing some of the exceptions:
http://paste.debian.net/189517

I have deployed the geoexplorer.war file in jboss 5.1.x but deployement failed. I get the following error when I run geoexplorer:

> ringo/global not found or not readable

What do I need to do in order to deploy GeoExplorer in jboss 5.1.x?

Answer (score 1):

https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/geoexplorer_deployment_on_jboss_5_1_0_g